# Even Empty application does not execute in Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I tried to search for all types of answers but i didnt get it . 
First i tried to solve . sqlite -v 1.3.9 probelm by adding

```
group:development, :test do
   gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production, :staging do
   gem 'pg'
   gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and it removed the pg problem for installing -v 1.17.0.1 something . Then i again got some warnings to install the rails factor which you can see in my last config file above. Still the page does not exist in the heroku page . Its is an empty application following michael hartls Chapter 1. Im new to this so i dont find a perfect place to find the required code for this .

I cant attach my log here :/.

EDIT : LOG FILE BELOW

http://pastebin.com/CNTsMYXK

Comment: copy the log and paste it in the question.

Comment: hartl uses `postgres` and there are many heroku guides on setting that up.  See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4)

Comment: It's a good idea to use the same database in your local and production environments.  Since Heroku uses postgres, you're better off setting up a postgres database.

Comment: Have you defined any routes in your application?

Comment: No @Nitish . Its just the basic starts of the Michael hartl book

Comment: @ecleel Added it through paste bin . Please check it out

Comment: @Anthony I installed postgresql and sqlite3 both and removed gemlock file and installed bundle done git add . and commit and when i try to push . It pushes . But the web does not open . t just says there is a problem in the page

Comment: What happens when you run heroku logs

Comment: @MohanRajan try to remove sqlite3 and keep only pg and rails_12factor and put it without group block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set up any root route yet.

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):

In the tutorial you are following, it is mentioned that the application won't work on Heroku at this point of time. The application should work once you add a root route to your application at later stages in that tutorial.

See: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#uid98

If you want to make it work now, add a root route as follows:

Add this to config/routes.rb

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

Add this to app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render text: "Hello World"
  end
end
```